# ESXi 7 lost root password after update

Tags: vmware-esxi

I had a woring ESXi 6.5 installation.  SSH and access to portal was possible.

I had the need to upgrad to latest ESXi 7.  I updated it from 6.5 -> 6.7 -> 7.0.

After updating, the datastore was no more recognized.  Read in some forums that it needs a licnese.  So I installed a license and rebooted.

After this reboot, the root password does not work anymore.  Dont know what went wrong in between.

Anyone can give any clues?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Knowledge Base](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1317898), the only way to reset the root password is to reinstall the server.

There is not really a way to know what went wrong. The upgrade to 6.7 was unnecessary though, 6.5 -> 7.0 is a supported migration path.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My question was more in terms of what could have caused this password loss and did vmware reset the password to something?

Comment: No, I've done a lot of ESXi Upgrades over the years and never experienced this issue. You could open a case with VMware, but without access to the server logs this is most probably fruitless.